# how do i use the @Import css rule?

Tags: html, css

ive been using css for a while now and ive used @import rule before and it has worked, im working on a project where it's not working, anyone willing to help? here is the code

```
@import url('media.css');
nav ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}
.burger{
    align-self: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

now this is the code being imported(media.css)

```
@media screen and (width <= 600px){
    nav ul{ display: none;}
    .burger{ display: flex;}
}
```

i have had to add a css link in the html file, its the only thing that seems to work

Comment: Do you use any compiler or any task runner?

Comment: no, im not using any compiler

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears unrelated to `@import`.

Your imported stylesheet defines some rules (conditionally, based on the width).

Then the next bit of CSS **overrides every one of those rules** using identical (i.e. equal [specificity](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-4/#cascade-specificity)) selectors which win the cascade because they are [defined later](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-4/#cascade-order).

Comment: i haven't really thought about it like that. let me change the code and ill let you know if it works